# Python Leibniz summation

Tags: python

[Leibniz summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baHSG.png)

I'm trying to get leibniz summation with python, but, with my code, I'm getting slightly different value. I can't find why it's not giving me the right answer.

```
import math
def estimate_pi( iterations ):
    pi = 0.0
    for n in range(0,iterations+1):
        pi = pi + (math.pow(-1,n)/((2*n)+1))
    return pi

print("How many iterations?")
print(estimate_pi(int(input())))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summation does not estimate `pi`, it estimates `pi/4`. So change the code to something like:

```
def estimate_pi( iterations ):
    sum = 0.0
    for n in range(iterations):
        sum += (math.pow(-1,n)/((2*n)+1))
    # sum now estimates pi/4, so return sum * 4 ~ (pi/4) * 4 ~ pi
    return (sum * 4)

print estimate_pi(100000)
```

**Output:**

```
3.14158265359
```

Comment: ye, but still it's giving me slightly different value than others summation pi code :(

Comment: I was going to *4 to get a pi value. but before that, I think my equation is wrong in some point

Comment: @buq333 In addition to multiplying the return value by `4`, I also corrected the range to reflect the summation equation (i.e. `range(iterations)` instead of `range(iterations+1)`.

Comment: oh, nevermind. 'iterations+1' was the reason. I changed to just 'iterations' and it's fixed. Thanks btw.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!